# With rails audits gem, can we add an audit manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, audit

I noticed that devise uses (under the hood) essentially an update_all on the user, to increment the failed_attempts. This means that there is no after_commit hook on the user object, so the audited gem doesn't record the changes made by devise.

Technically the record did change, and it would be super useful to have a log of failed login attempts.

Is there a "good" way to add an audit record?  Even if I could do so with just a comment about the bad attempt

Looking for best practice.

Answer (score 0):

In general there're several ways for data to change without `audited` even noticing it - `update_all`, `connection.execute`, from non-rails processes in complex applications, within database itself via stored procedures/triggers. Thus there's no generic solution at rails/gem level (apart from trigger-based inside the database itself).

For your particular task - you can use warden's `before_failure` callback (devise runs on top of warden, see [warden wiki](https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki/Callbacks) for callback doc), like:

```
Warden::Manager.before_failure do |env, opts|
  request = Rack::Request.new(env)
  user = User.find_by(email: request.params[:email]) # not sure about param name
  if user
    user.audits.create(action: "update", audit_comment: "failed login from ...")
  end
end
```

But note that this may make your app vulnerable to a timing attack - because of db write app will answer attempts with correct email and wrong password slightly slower thus attacker can detect valid emails